# ADODB Recordset Binding in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, 64-bit, adodb

I have an old VB6 application that uses ADODB recorsets with ODBC connections.  The application hs worked fine on Windows XP for years.  I tried installing it on 3 different Windows 7 64 bit machines and I get error 545 - Unable to bind to field or DataMember: 'FieldName'.

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
    For Each oText In Me.txtFields
        Set oText.DataSource = rsLocationInfo
        oText.Locked = True
    Next
```

Thanks for your help.  I have been trying to research and fix this all day.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I'm not sure which data (MDAC?) component was incorrect, but simply installing the Access 2007 runtime on the machines solved the problem.  If we continue to use the old VB6 app, we need to revisit our installation package.  For now, we're good to go until we rewrite the old app.